# How to call a randomized loot table method again from within itself to prevent duplicates in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I have a basic loot table with weighted drop rarities. I am trying to make it so that when the game starts, it will re-roll if the item already exists in a duplicated list.

I've created an empty list in `shopManagerScript` and am adding each instantiated item to that list. Then I would like to check against that list to see if the item exists. If it does, I want to re-roll again. If it doesn't then go ahead and instantiate the item.

This current code is executing endlessly however, and is crashing my game.

```
public GameObject shopManager;
public ShopManager shopManagerScript;

[System.Serializable]
public class DropItem
{
    public string name;
    public GameObject item;
    public int dropRarity;
}

public List<DropItem> ShopItemPool = new List<DropItem>();

private void Start()
{

    shopManager = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("ShopManager");
    shopManagerScript = shopManager.GetComponent<ShopManager>();
    SpawnItem();
}
void SpawnItem()
{
    int itemWeight = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < ShopItemPool.Count; i++)
    {
        itemWeight += ShopItemPool[i].dropRarity;
    }

    int randomValue = Random.Range(0, itemWeight);

    for (int i = 0; i < ShopItemPool.Count; i++)
    {
        if (randomValue <= ShopItemPool[i].dropRarity && !shopManagerScript.shopItems.Contains(ShopItemPool[i].item.ToString()))
        {
            Instantiate(ShopItemPool[i].item, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
            shopManagerScript.shopItems.Add(ShopItemPool[i].item.ToString());
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            SpawnItem();
        }

        randomValue -= ShopItemPool[i].dropRarity;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you have 2 items with the same rarity at the start of your item pool, wont this code only ever try to get the first item?  Have you tried using `continue` instead of running the entire function again?

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that `SpawnItem` method calls `SpawnItem` inside the `for`, which results in having more running `SpawnItem`. Then these running `SpawnItem` call more `SpawnItem`. The process continues until stack is overflowed and it falls with StackOverflowException.

In order to fix this you can use `continue` as mentioned before, but be careful with calling `SpawnItem`, because if the random keeps generating inappropriate values the method can still be called too many times and the error will be the same.

Another way to fix it is to **remove recursive call** of it and make another method that loops calling `SpawnItem`. Just make sure that the logic of looping doesn't fully rely on random, otherwise it's still possible to call the method too many times